# ERROR: Could not open file lib\fontconfig.properties.src

Tags: install4j

When running an install4j installer, the process stops during the extraction. From the log:

...

extracting lib\fontconfig.properties.src (size 10479)

ERROR: Could not open file lib\fontconfig.properties.src

This is on a Windows 7 32bit desktop. When I try it on my own laptop with a similar setup, it works correctly.

What could be causing this and how can I solve it?

Comment: Looks like a Java issue to me, but can't really say more.

Comment: What action produces this error?